# how can select timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

hy I have uisng laravel 4
I have data like this: 2016-02-12 18:32:19
I have query like this

```
 echo $result = SourceManagement::get(array('id', 'created_at', DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(created_at), '%Y') as created_at")));  

 // print_r($result);
```

why Output to be like this :

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":7,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":8,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":9,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":10,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":11,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":12,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":13,
      "created_at":null
   },
   {  
      "id":14,
      "created_at":null
   }
]
```

Comment: How you want to show your date? can you tell the date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query like this, that might solve your problem, as per my understanding you are overwriting the default column name, thats why you getting null, I tested below query, its working fine.

```
$result = SourceManagement::get(array('id', 'created_at', DB::raw("date_format(created_at, '%Y') as created_at_custom")));
```